# what actually is a loop?

Tags: ruby, structure

I know that there are a couple ways to loop in various languages - a "for" loop, a "while" loop, a "do-while" loop, and just "loop" in Ruby for example. And I know there are various functions in every language that are pre-written in that language - for example the .each function in Ruby (which I think is based on a "for" loop and written entirely in Ruby and is replicable just using the language).

But what is the logic behind loops? Are they programmed from control flow statements in Assembly or even binary? And in fact, now that i think about it, what is the origin of all programming structures in general (such as variable name/value associations, arrays, hashes, etc - sorry if my terminology is wrong). Can anyone recommend sources to read more on this?

Comment: That's a lot of questions - some of them very open ended. It doesn't fit Stack Overflow.

Comment: Agree with @NielsB. I'd also add that `each` is not functionally identical to `for` ... a variable created and initialized in a for block is available when you exit the for block, not so with an each block.

Comment: I think you want to read a book on computer algorithms. The origin of everything in computing is simply a need to solve problems more efficiently. And a loop in assembly is simply the CPU jumping back a certain number of steps in execution flow, and then re-executing what it just jumped over. There's not much magic there. To end the loop a conditional jump is used, which determines if the jump back is performed or if execution continues forward.

Comment: thanks @Casper can you recommend a good one for a relative beginner?

Comment: This is the one I read when studying CS. If you want the nitty gritty details of what makes algorithms work, and how to use them, then it's a good place to start and you can have it as a reference in your bookshelf for many years to come: "Algorithms by Robert Sedgewick".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loops in general are jumps in the program flow. When you compile your code i.e. in C, it gets "converted" to assembly, where you can see that loop structure:
So you start at a certain adress and do some stuff  (i.e. ADD) which basically is everything inside your loop. At the very end then is a jump instruction back to the adress where you started. Breaking is is then i.e. made through a conditional jump inside your loop and thus you don't get to the jump instruction again and therefore do not loop again.